# Crystal Reports doesn't show any data

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, .net-3.5, crystal-reports

So I'm using this SQL Server with my application and I decided to display crystal reports to the user. I'm not at all experienced with crystal reports, but this project gives me a good opportunity to learn.

Now, my data sources are already setup and i've been using them with for the past several months with this project. However, when I create a report using Crystal Report's wizard and I include data, I get no data output. I get the labels, but no actual data from the database. When I go to report's preview I see an example and it looks right, however no data is displayed.

I also tried creating a graph, but that didn't even show up.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you linking tables? In my experience 99% of the time when I get no data with Crystal it's been because of a funky link.  Also check what part of the report (Header, details, etc.) the object is in.

Comment: What do you mean? There's a foreign key between two of the tables I'm trying to display, but even when I'm only displaying one table, nothing is shown.

Comment: BTW, you can edit your question, even if you can't add a comment

Comment: Check the links in Crystal Reports datasource (not SQL server)

Comment: There's one valid link which is a left join on a foreign key

Comment: Ah, got it working, had to add every table instead of just the two tables.

Answer (score 0):

I sometimes hit trouble because I need a left join when the default is an inner join.